# Object oriented lua sans underlying associative container mechanics

Tags: oop, optimization, lua

Is there any syntactic sugar to use object oriented lua by leveraging the array part of the lua table construct ?

```
-- foo_index == number
local foo_index = global_bar_object_prototype.foo; 
bar[foo_index]("hello world"];

--vs.
-- file 2 bar.foo type == function
bar.foo("hello world");

-- both versions call the same function with the same input
```

I was hoping luajit would do inter chunk string interning to optimise/cache the string-key access giving it array-like access characteristics. However my naive benchmark disproved the assumption. I am hoping my benchmark logic is flawwed in which case I would not need to look for syntactic sugar.

What Are the idioms that make object oriented lua have O(1)(function lookup) characteristics for high performance scripting purposes ? I'm sure game interface programmers have seen these first hand.

Comment: Man, you can't throw the stone and then hide the hand :) where is that benchmark?

Comment: I'll put it up when I get to my desktop :)

Comment: @HassanSyed - Why did you apply the [tag:embedded] tag to this question?  Please read the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info), and either explain how it applies here or remove it. Thanks!

Comment: The application area is lua in a resource constraned embedded platform. The people who embed lua in that domain have mostly likely encountered this issue.

Comment: @HassanSyed: The "embedded" tag refers to *embedded systems*, not embedding scripting languages. So I removed it.

Comment: "What Are the idioms that make object oriented lua have O(n)(function lookup) characteristics for high performance scripting purposes ?" Are you sure you mean `O(n)` here? Array lookup should be `O(1)`, and Lua already has `O(log(n))` for lookups from tables.

Comment: I meant embedded systems NOT language embedding.....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question, but if you're asking whether there is a way to define a bar table as an object such that

```
bar[foo_index]("hello")
```

will work, yes there is a way: the metatable of bar should define the __index so it can take an integer as key and return the associated method. Somewhere in the bar "constructor" you define the mapping of indices to "methods"; the __index would look at that mapping and return the function.

You would probably also add a method that would take a method name and return the corresponding index, so caller doesn't have to know what mapping constructor creates:

```
foo_index = bar.getMethodIndex('foo')
bar[foo_index]("hello")
```

Another optimization allowed by lua is

```
foo_meth = bar.foo
foo_meth(bar, "hello")
```